# How to create a horizontally centered menu in CSS while having different distances between menu items

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem creating a horizontally centered menu with different distances between menu items. It's cracking up each time. I am zooming my display (for some reason, I can't attach a pic right here, but I hope you get the idea). So, it's not stable. Any ideas to make it adaptive to different page zoom?

I just need a horizontal menu which would be stable. Each menu item has `115px` in width, but different distance between each other. Here are the distances between each element:

- `87px` between the 1st and 2nd elements
- `56px` between the 2nd and 3rd elements
- `29px` between 3rd and 4th elements

Thank you in advance, hope someone would help.

```css
.nav-menu {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.site-nav {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 624px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.site-nav a {
  color: #626262;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.site-nav li:nth-child(1) {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 124px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-top: 76px;
}

.site-nav li:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 108px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-top: 76px;
}

.site-nav li:nth-child(3) {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 106px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-top: 76px;
}

.site-nav li:last-child {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  margin-top: 76px;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-menu">
  <ul class="site-nav">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Lifestyle</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give `margin-right` values in percent and not in pixels.
For example: `margin-right: 5%;`
You have to figure out which percent is similar to the pixel value but it´s better than a not working navbar. 
If I got your Question right this should be what you mean.